# Linear-gradient e compatibilidade com navegadores

Tags: css, css3

Estou utilizando o seguinte css de background em um menu:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444); /* Standard syntax */
```

Porém, em navegadores (como o IE) que ele não funciona, o menu fica sem background. Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar uma cor opcional caso o navegador não entenda essa propriedade, como se fosse uma cor default, de fundo.
Sei que tenho duas opções: tornar a propriedade compatível com todas ou adicionar essa segunda opção de cor solida.  Como agir?

Comment: PS: Não funciona em versões anteriores a 10, nas recentes funciona normalmente. No [**Edge**](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/gradients) também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para os browsers antigos, basta você definir um `background` solido, sem o gradiente, assim:

```
background: #444; //ou outra cor que você queira
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0260a9, #444);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #0260a9, #444);
```

Mas tudo depende das especificações e público que você vai atingir. Em meus trabalhos, dificilmente me preocupo com navegadores antigos, pois meus clientes trabalham sempre com coisas mais modernas, então 'voltar atrás' e se preocupar com esses 'fix' não é viável para o meu caso.

Comment: Resposta perfeita! Realmente, a estrutura é e deve ser bastante relativa ao público alvo que seu trabalho deve atingir. Obrigado, espero que ajude outras pessoas. ;)